# How to run Embedded Visual Basic on modern PC

Tags: vbscript, embedded, windows-ce, emulation

I try to use this abandoned software to teach newbie with Visual Basic 6 knowledges only.

I know this software is not recommended for real-world development.

I have installed eVB (full install) on Virtual PC machine with Windows XP mode 
I tried to run application on emulator. Firewall allowed this connection.

But I've got message:
Emulator for windows CE will not run within another copy of emulator for windows ce

As I mentioned this problem, with no workaround:
VPC and the Emulators use the same emulation engine, and so the emulators think you're trying to run them inside another emulator instance because they can't tell the difference.

1) Is there possible to run eVB on Win7 PC?
2) Is there possible to run eVB on VmWare PC with Windows 2000/Windows XP?
3) Is there free alternative to eVB for learning purposes only?

Comment: Use VBA in Excel? That's about the only place you would still use the VB language in the year 2014.

Comment: Is there solution http://blog.newtrics.com/?p=176 ?

Comment: I have old cheap hardware for 50 USD with Windows CE .NET 4.1/4.2 - I have idea newbie should learn also on real device. Therefore eVB, VBA is only imitation/surrogate. eVB is the first candidate. Is there modern alternatives? Quick cycle "Design GUI -> write code -> Compile -> Deploy -> Debug" is very important

Comment: The modern alternative would be a PC. Modern languages would be Java, C# and C++. You should not teach VB to beginners, you are wasting their time on learning a dead language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the emulators will not run in a VM.

I do question to value of using eVB, as it's definitely a dead technology, and there's very little use for the VB6/VBA syntax any longer.

If you're trying to teach the basics of programming in general the I'd get an Express version of Visual Studio and teach VB.NET or C# for a simple, standard desktop application.  Most of the knowledge there would be transferrable to a device.

If developing for a Windows CE device is a hard requirement, then I'd probably try finding an old version of Visual Studio (2005 or 2008) and using VB.NET or C# in the Compact Framework for those.  My guess is that your best route there would be to try to find the eval version of Platform Builder (Windows Embedded Compact 7) which would give you something like 90 or 120 days.

The express edition of the newest versions of Studio also allow targeting Windows Phone, which has an emulator and supports VB.NET or C#.

And of course you could even try using Xamarin Studio and target Mono against an Android emulator.  Again, you'd get C# on a device, though the UI paradigm is *way* different than anything for CE or Windows Phone.

If you simply want to write BASIC code for am embedded device, Parallax has the [BASIC Stamp](http://www.parallax.com/catalog/microcontrollers/basic-stamp), which has pretty cheap starter kits.  If you're after .NET on an embedded device, [Netduino](http://www.netduino.com/) might be what you're after (I think they have VB.NET support).

Really I guess the question is "what's the end goal?"  To learn general programming?  If so, just use a desktop machine to start with.  To apply programming knowledge to an embedded device?  Then get something with more up-to-date support.

Regardless of the goal, I have a hard time coming up with a valid reason for trying to use eVB.

Comment: >Yes, the emulators will not run in a VM.
Only in Virtual PC emulators?